# Bang! Fistful and Boots

Tags: bang

What happens with fistful and boots? Do you draw for the hits from fistful between the hits?

Boots (1 stock, 3 cost, black border) For each lost life point, you draw 1 card from deck.

A Fistful of Cards: at the beginning of his turn, each player is the target of as many Bang! as the number of cards in his hand.

Answer (score 1):

Each bang is coming in as a separate event so you will draw a card each time you take damage.  Just like if you had a barrel and you would flip for each one.  Also if you are playing the character with the same ability as boots you would draw for each one.